# jquery datepicker year range default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Having a bit of an issue with the JQuery `datePicker`, I suspect it's just the matter of a setting I've overlooked or got wrong.

If you look at this simple fiddle: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9fwL/2/)

You'll see I've set the year range, so that the by default when you click on the input it will open it up on 1994, but if you then click on any of those dates, e.g. 3rd Sept, it'll actually put it in the input as 2012 still, rather than the year that is selected in the drop down menu.

How can I make it so that it uses the correct year without having to change the drop down and then change it back again?

Cheers.

Comment: It seems to be a Datepicker Jquery Plugin bug... I have the same problem with : `yearRange: "1994:2010"`

Comment: maybe it's already filled as bug code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=177

Comment: That is not the same bug that this could be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird, but adding `defaultDate:"1994-01-01"` to the datepicker options seems to fix it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9fwL/11/)

Answer (score 9):

As others have suggested, you have to set the defaultDate. However, unlike the other solutions, you don't want to hardcode the date since your dropdown list will be updating as the years pass since you're doing a relative list.

Try this instead...

```
function loadDatePicker() {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: "-18:-12",
        defaultDate:"-18y-m-d"  // Relative year/month/day
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The way I incorporated it was to just decrement currentYear by 18 and stick that in rather than an actual hard coded year, but i'll try yours as well.

Comment: @jascav This is best way.

Comment: This should be the best answer, as it does the job without hardcoding or computation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the reason..
It is because yearRange: just restrict the range in dropdown menu only.
It just change the list nothing else.

They mansion this over here..

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange
[Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the minDate and/or maxDate options.]

To Prove this .. set date picker as below and you will find all date disable.
because it sawing us the calander of 2012 not 1994

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
         changeYear: true,
         changeMonth: true,
         yearRange: "-18:-12",
         maxDate: new Date(2012,1-1,1)

     });
```

To fix it you have to use defaultDate as well as minDate and maxDate

i hope i am clear