# selected date of Jquery datepicker is wrong

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i just Changed the year Range is 1960 to 2003

but i got current year on the textbox while I'm selecting Date 
for instance if i selected march-4-1960 but it displays  '03/04/2015'

[image]

Code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#txt1" ).datepicker(
    {

     changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1960:2003'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
```

Comment: show me what u tried so far ?

Comment: @CodingCracker I couldnt add my fiddle link in my Question. 
http://jsfiddle.net/King_Fisher/pqpa8gy6/2/

Comment: if it working please accept my answer @king fisher

Comment: @CodingCracker please see my comments in your answer

Comment: This looks to be a bug... in how the draw year is calculated....

Comment: @CodingCracker 
 
If I select march-5 1960 or any date then it shows ''03/01/1960" .check your fiddle pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pqpa8gy6/5/)

```
   $(function() {
$( "#txt1" ).datepicker({    
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1960:2003',
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
         var startDate = new Date(dateText);


        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, inst.selectedDay));
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: but the date is always ''03/01/1960" ? why? did u note that?

Comment: I mean the day part  not changed . you assigned the default day as 1

Comment: If I select march-5 1960 or any date then it shows  ''03/01/1960" .check your fiddle pls. @Coding Cracker

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is by setting a `defaultDate`. I believe this approach is much cleaner.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqpa8gy6/4/)

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#txt1" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1960:2003"
        defaultDate:"1994-01-01"
    });
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408024/586051)

[`defaultDate` jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

---

[Re-updated jsFiddle based on your comment.](http://jsfiddle.net/pqpa8gy6/7/)

Comment: @King_Fisher Not sure how you checked for year 2020. Please checkout the re-updated jsFiddle that supports year 2020: http://jsfiddle.net/pqpa8gy6/7/ Answer updated.